# Synonym für Angst (Übersetzung für terrify)

Tags: word-choice, single-word-request, synonym

Mit welchem Wort könnte man so genau wie möglich eine sehr sehr große, unbeschreibliche, Angst vor etwas beschreiben? (Haha)
Ich würde nämlich gerne den Satz "Das macht mir Angst." ein wenig aufpeppen.
Ich kann es leider nicht sehr gut beschreiben, aber es geht dabei nicht um etwas, das einen erschreckt, oder paralysiert, sondern eher um Ehrfurcht vor etwas, das größer ist als man selbst. Auf Englisch würde ich den Satz "That terrifies me." schreiben, falls das weiterhilft…
Folgende Wörter sind meiner Meinung nach eher unpassend:

- ängstigt/verängstigt *(Das klingt meiner Meinung nach ein wenig jämmerlich und ist außerdem nicht stark genug)*
- erschreckt *(Es ist einfach nicht **erschreckend**. Meine Figur überlegt sehr lange und kommt dann auf den Schluss, dass sie Angst hat.)*
- erschüttert *(Siehe **erschreckt** - es ist ungefähr das selbe.)*
- bestürzt *(Ebenfalls.)*
- entsetzt *(Das selbe.)*
- einschüchternd *(Das trifft es von allen am besten, aber es ist nicht nur **einschüchternd**; das ist einfach wieder nicht stark genug.)*
- ehrfürchtig *(Ähnlich wie **einschüchternd**. Aber "Das macht mich ehrfürchtig." klingt einfach falsch.)*
- graut *(Das Wort verbinde ich leider immer mit Gruselgeschichten und das ist die falsche Richtung.)*
- lähmt/paralysiert *(Die Person ist schlicht und ergreifend nicht gelähmt vor Angst.)*
- entmutigt *(Sie ist auch nicht entmutigt. Die Angst sieht sie, wenn überhaupt, als Herausforderung)*

Ich hoffe, ich bin nicht einfach von Englisch verwöhnt, und es gibt tatsächlich ein Wort dafür. Sonst müsste mein Charakter wohl etwas anderes sagen.
In dem Fall wäre ich natürlich auch für Vorschläge offen. :-)

---

Edit:
Tut mir Leid, das hätte ich vorher sagen müssen: Es geht um Liebe. Meine Figur hat Angst davor, wie stark ihre Gefühle sind. Ich hoffe, das hilft weiter.

Comment: Kurioserweise würde man auf Englisch für *eine sehr sehr große, unbeschreibliche Angst* einfach **angst** schreiben.

Comment: @Janka Ja, das stimmt schon, aber ich hätte lieber ein Verb. Und ich muss zugeben, dass ich das Wort "angst" noch nie sehr passend fand.

Comment: Ich verstehe noch nicht, war genau Du ausdrücken willst. Kannst Du vielleicht erklären, _warum_ die aufgelisteten Wörter unpassend sind?

Comment: ... oder einfach mal darlegen, was das denn für ein unbeschreibliches, großes Ding ist, das dir nicht Ehrfurcht einflößt, das dich nicht entmutigt oder lähmt, vor der dir auch nicht graut, das dich nicht erschreckt oder entsetzt und dessentwegen du auch nicht verängstigt bist. Das muss ja ein sehr spezielles Ding sein, dass dir solche unbeschreiblichen Gefühle gibt...

Comment: Da es um eine Geschichte zu gehen scheint, und es offenbar kein griffiges Verb gib, hilft vielleicht das "Show - don't tell" Prinzip weiter, also z.B _Als ich X sah/ hörte/ realisierte/...wurden meine Knie weich/ begann ich zu zittern / wurde ich bleich etc._   https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Show,_don%E2%80%99t_tell

Comment: @Marzipanherz: Ich muss definitiv lernen Fragen genauer zu formulieren. Die Person sagt, dass sie Angst hat bzw. dass ihr etwas Angst macht. Deswegen kann man das so ein bisschen schwer darstellen.

Answer (score 3):

Die Beschreibung "Ehrfurcht vor etwas, das größer ist als man selbst" könnte mit

> Heidenrespekt

bezeichnet werden. Das schließt die Aversion aus und geht etwas weniger in Richtung der "Angst" im eigentlichen Wortsinn.

Answer (score 2):

In deiner Frage sprichst du von sehr großer Angst im Sinne von Ehrfurcht. Dazu fällt mir ein:

> vor etwas einen [Horror](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Horror) haben

Beispiel:

> Als einfacher Hilfsarbeiter habe ich einen Horror davor, ins Zimmer
>   des Konzernchefs zu müssen.

Comment: Das ist theoretisch nicht falsch, aber das impliziert leider, dass die Figur eine Art Aversion dagegen hat, die andere (angsteinflößende) Person zu sehen. Das ist nicht die Richtung, in die ich gehen wollte. Aber trotzdem danke.

Answer (score 2):

Man könnte ängstlich mit "panisch" steigern. Nur so eine Idee :)

Comment: You know what? Warum nicht! "Das macht mir panische Angst." klingt nicht seltsam. Wenn es mir später nicht mehr gefällt, werd ich eben Pech gehabt haben. Danke, manchmal liegt die Lösung direkt vor den Augen. :)

Answer (score 2):

Die steigerte Form von *terrify* is *petrify* im Englischen. Für das Wort *petrify* verwendet man eine Redewendung wie:

> Versteinert vor Angst

Answer (score 1):

Es wäre hilfreich gewesen, der Fragesteller hätte - anstatt alle Wörter aufzuzählen, die nicht passen - einmal das Ding benannt, dass ihm (oder seiner Figur) solche unbeschreiblichen Gefühle macht. Das muss ja ein sehr bemerkenswertes Ding sein. Ein schrecklicher Engel vielleicht? Oder das Universum als solches? Ohne den Auslöser zu kennen, kann man als lexikalischer Berater nur ratend herumeiern.

Hier mein Beitrag zum Herumeiern:

> Bammel haben
>
> einen Heidenbammel haben
>
> ergriffen sein
>
> jesusmäßig ergriffen sein
>
> vor Ehrfurcht auf die Knie fallen
>
> wie vom Donner gerührt sein
>
> vor Erfurcht erstarren
>
> sich angesichts des Unermesslichen fühlen wie ein Staubkorn im All
>
> den Hauch der Ewigkeit verspüren

Answer (score 0):

Dein wie nebenbei hingeworfener Satz "meine Figur überlegt sehr lange und kommt dann zum Schluß, dass sie Angst hat" - Funktioniert mit "Angst" im Deutschen nicht richtig (funktioniert's im Englischen? Keine Ahnung, wahrscheinlich auch nicht). "Angst" ist eine Emotion und in den allerseltensten Fällen das Ergebnis eines kognitiven Prozesses.

Nach langer Überlegung kann man allenfalls *eine Bedrohung*, *eine Gefahr* oder *ein Risiko* erkennen oder wahrnehmen.

Ist dir das zu schwach, kannst du das eben weiter qualifizieren, z.B.:

> ... erkannte er die furchtbare Bedrohung, die von dem Tier ausging...
>
> ... sah sie das schreckliche Risiko, dem sie sich ausgesetzt hatte ...
>
> ... nahm er das wahre Ausmaß der Gefahr war, in der er schwebte ...

Comment: Da hab ich mich wohl ein wenig schwammig ausgedrückt. Die Figur hat vor einer Person Angst, bzw. nicht direkt vor der Person, sondern... wie soll ich sagen... den Gefühlen, die diese Person bei meiner Figur auslöst. Sie erzählt sozusagen einer anderen Figur, dass sie Angst davor hat. Wenn es das ein bisschen verständlicher macht; ich drücke mich oft ein wenig unklar aus.

Comment: Jetzt muss ich lachen, weil du eine Frage nach einer *perfekten Formulierung* mit einer unklar formulierten Frage stellst. Wenn du so perfekt formulieren willst, solltest du vielleicht auch besser auf die Formulierung deiner Fragen achten ;) Und: Ich kann mir leider immer noch nicht genau vorstellen, was du eigentlich sagen willst. Am besten, du lieferst uns mehr Kontext, statt aufzuzählen, was alles nicht paßt - Das weißt du ja schon. Und bitte arbeite die Klarstellungen in deine ursprüngliche Frage ein, damit man sich das nicht aus Kommentaren zusammensuchen muß.

Comment: Da hast du vermutlich recht. Ich bin im Moment einfach ein wenig verwirrt, glaube ich. Aber zur Angst wollte ich noch sagen: Man kann ja auch z.B. Platzangst haben, aber das in dem Moment, in dem man sie hat, nicht realisieren, dass man sie hat.

Answer (score 0):

Wie wäre es ganz einfach mit

> ehrfürchtig

?

Fehlt dem Begriff eventuell heutzutage die Furcht?

Aber wenn Deine Figur lange überlegt, kannst Du es ja auch lang beschreiben.

Comment: Theoretisch ginge das schon, aber ich persönlich finde es einfach seltsam "Das macht mich ehrfürchtig." (oder einen ähnlichen Satz mit Ehrfurcht) zu sagen... Als Gedanke vielleicht schon, aber nicht ausgesprochen. Trotzdem danke. :-)

Answer (score 0):

"**eine schreckliche Ahnung haben**"!?

(eine Ahnung von etwas, das man eben noch nicht vollständig realisiert hat, wie du @Sebau-nu-mu in einem Kommentar weiter oben meintest)

"***schreckliche* Angst haben**"?!

Comment: Hmm. Auch nicht dumm... Ich glaub da muss ich mal drüber schlafen. Haha! Danke für die Antwort. :)